# Excel - want to conglomerate data from 2 columns then sort by unique strings and count

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to gather data from a project with 12 worksheets (1 for every month) with approximately 1000 rows monthly. Each row has both a listing firm and selling firm column.
I wish to filter both columns for every unique string and end up with a list/row for each company with a count of how many times they are listed. These rows then sorted descending numbers.
ie:

```
CENTURY         15
CENTRAL          4
CIR              4
PROFESSIONALS   3 etc.
SUTTON          3
HOUSE           1
URBAN           1
```

---

```
Listing Firm 1      Selling Firm 1 Name
CENTURY             CIR 
MOUNTAINVIEW        CENTURY 
CENTRAL             CENTURY 
CIR                 SUTTON  
CENTRAL             CENTRAL
PLINTZ              DIRECT
CENTURY             CIR 
CENTURY             CENTURY
DIRECT              CENTURY 
SUTTON              CIR
CENTURY             HOUSE
CENTURY             PROFESSIONALS
REALTY              CENTURY 
CENTRAL             CENTURY 
WALLER              HOUSE
PROFESSIONALS       CENTURY
PROFESSIONALS       CENTURY 
CENTURY             URBAN
CENTURY            SUTTON
```

I am thinking that I need to do this VBA. Not sure if this is the case or not.:
Can I somehow combine the 2 columns into one array 
then loop through the array for unique strings.
 and Assign that array to a variable (not sure how to use it for the next step though). I still need to go through the original 2000 or so entrys (column1 and column2) and total how many each Firm had.
I hope this makes sense to someone. I am trying to organize it to the best of my ability which is limited.
I am hoping for some guidance if my logic is correct and if so where to begin.
Thank you.  geddeca

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary can give you a unique list and count at the same time. Once the information is returned to the worksheet, a quick sort can be performed.

The following gathers and processes the information from a single worksheet. It should be relatively easy to loop through a dozen worksheets and process each.

- collect values from worksheet
- process dictionary of list and count
- return new values to worksheet
- sort values by count descending then name ascending

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub macro()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, w As Long
    Dim arr As Variant, dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.comparemode = vbTextCompare

    For w = 1 To 1
        With Worksheets(w)

            'collect values from worksheet
            arr = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Value2

            'process dictionary of list and count
            dict.RemoveAll
            For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
                    dict.Item(arr(i, j)) = dict.Item(arr(i, j)) + 1
                Next j
            Next i

            'return new values to worksheet
            .Cells(1, "D").Resize(1, 2) = Array("list", "count")
            .Cells(2, "D").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
            .Cells(2, "E").Resize(dict.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dict.items)

            'sort values by count descending then name ascending
            With .Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
                .Sort key1:=.Columns(2), order1:=xlDescending, _
                      key2:=.Columns(1), order2:=xlAscending, _
                      Header:=xlYes
            End With

        End With
    Next w

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I am not that familiar with the excel object but now I know about dictionary. I added a count of the worksheet collection on the loop and it loops through them all.  Thank you for this very useful code for me to learn from and use.  geddeca

Comment: Oh Oh,  I adjusted the code to have more columns and have now accidentally got columns D and E which now hold List and Sale Price numbers which are now being changed by the code because of my lack of understanding.  Here is what I tried to use. ok I am struggling to enter code. Not enough characters left. will try next.

Comment: You need to ask a new question with the revised code and a full description of the new conditions and any errors that are occurring.